# How does Microsoft TechNet Subscription work?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, windows-xp, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

I want to use TechNet to download Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 to two virtual machines.  I am not familiar with TechNet so I am hoping you can guide me in the right direction. :)  In the system requirements, it says you need a Windows 7 OS or other supported versions but I could not find any reference on the other supported versions at [this link.](http://www.microsoft.com/technetsubscription)  I only have a base Windows XP so I am hoping that will cut it.  When I use the TechNet on the Windows XP, how do I change the OS?  At this point, will the Windows XP OS be gone?  What happens after the 12 month subscription?  Does everything revert back to before?  Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's just start by saying that the TechNet software is not meant for production systems but for testing and development only.  You download the ISOs and then you install them on either a physical machine or a virtual machine.  You don't use TechNet "on the Windows XP", TechNet isn't an application, it's a membership.  After your membership expires you will no longer have access to the TechNet resources but you can keep your software for as long as you use it for testing and development only.

I think you probably need to read up on how virtual machines work and what you will need to create virtual machines. TechNet is not a hypervisor.

I use VMware products exclusively so I can't really recommend a good free hypervisor though I heard good things about [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) for just spinning up a test VM running on your desktop.

**EDIT to respond to reply:**
Ok, so you will need to sign into TechNet with a Windows Live ID.  Then on the right side there's a TechNet box and a My Account link.  Once you get to the account page there will be an Activate My Subscription link on the top left.  That's what the activation key is for, once you are activated you can get the software through the download section.

Comment: I was only given an activation key.  Maybe the key is meant to dl the ISOs, so I will check on that.  I know TechNet is not a hypervisor, I only wanted TechNet for the operating systems.

Comment: The answer above is incorrect stating you can use a Technet sub for development purposes.  That is incorrect, Microsoft clearly states in quite a few places that Technet subs CANNOT be used for development.  MSDN subs are for development purposes.  From Technet license terms at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/cc294422.aspx